# ¿Como le coloco una coma al separador de miles?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

aca hice un pequeño ejemplo a ver si alguien me ayuda, no tengo conocimiento en Js , se podría decir que muy muy poco...apenas si tome un par de clases de introducción, en fin, lo que quiero es saber como se le aplica un separador de miles a este ejemplo , esto con el fin de guiarme para otro trabajo que estoy haciendo.
**Lo que quiero es que en lugar de 6500 aparezca como 6,500**

````
var eNvio = 1500;
var toTal = Subtotal + eNvio;

document.getElementById('pago').innerHTML =  Subtotal + eNvio + toTal ;


<div id="pago"></div> ```
````

Comment: Prueba a usar el [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl/NumberFormat). Hay ejemplos un poco más abajo para que veas cómo se usa, así como cómo se configura para adecuarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias , no lo hice con una funcion porque no supe como pero lo hice asi 


`document.getElementById('pago').innerHTML = toTal.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") ;`

Esto para que me de un resultado asi por ejemplo
6,500.00

y para que me separe miles lo hice asi 
`document.getElementById('pago').innerHTML = toTal.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "&nbsp"") ;`

Esto para que me de un resultado asi por ejemplo
6 500.00

Imagino que no es precisamente la manera correcta...pero me saco del apuro

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la siguiente funcion simple, para agregar la coma:

```js
    const addComa = (x) => { return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); } 

    console.log(addComa (6500 ));
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias , no lo hice con una funcion porque no supe como pero lo hice asi 


`document.getElementById('pago').innerHTML = toTal.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") ;`

Esto para que me de un resultado asi por ejemplo
6,500.00

y para que me separe miles lo hice asi 
`document.getElementById('pago').innerHTML = toTal.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "&nbsp"") ;`

Esto para que me de un resultado asi por ejemplo
6 500.00

Imagino que no es precisamente la manera correcta...pero me saco del apuro

Comment: Pues ya que usaste su solución, marca la respuesta como válida, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Te debería bastar simplemente usar **[NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl/NumberFormat)** como te dijo el colega en los comentarios.

Un ejemplo práctico es

```js
const value = Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(3500)
console.log(value)
```

De esta manera estas convirtiendo el valor en el formato que le pasas por parámetro a la función *NumberFormat*.

Nos comentas si es lo que buscas :)